# Как реализовать запуск функции при нажатии на один из LineEdit-ов с возвращением указателя на сам lineEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5

То есть у меня есть список lineEdit-ов, и при нажатии на один из них я хочу реализовать запуск определенной функции, которой в качестве параметра будет передаваться сам элемент, на который было совершено нажатие

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: проблема в том, что я даже не знаю, как отследить событие нажатия на lineEdit, извините :)

Comment: покажите то, что у вас есть.

Comment: просто расскажите, как отследить нажатие на lineEdit) я уж сам постараюсь)

Comment: как вам будет угодно. Читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#returnPressed

Comment: я знал, что этот вопрос будет максимально тупым... я просто долго не мог найти этой функции... Спасибо за помощь и за нормальное отношение к такому мне)

Comment: вопрос как вопрос, но если вам действительно будет нужна помощь, то вам надо будет предоставить пример вашего приложения.

Comment: В следующий раз буду учтительнее с этим